# Typescript version 3.7.2 and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Anybody knows anything about what version of Angular will start support Typescript > 3.7

Comment: 3.8 is the latest version of TypeScript, there is no 7.3.2

Comment: check https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript

Comment: sorry typing error

Comment: Getting this ,ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0 but 3.7.2 was found instead.

Comment: in package.json set typescript version as 3.4.0. Then `npm i`

Comment: If you using angular 9 rc, then you can ignore typescript version check by adding `{
  // ...
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true
  }
}` to tsconfig.json file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9427395/dasunse I am looking for Typescript > 3.7

Comment: vinay-sharma I am currently using @angular/cdk: 8.2.3